# como se usa esta API para saber el precio de HTG?

Tags: php, ajax, json

necesito saber el equivalente de 1 dolar en precio HTG moneda Haitiana

tengo este pequeño script:

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://fixer-fixer-currency-v1.p.rapidapi.com/symbols");

req.headers({
       "x-rapidapi-host": "fixer-fixer-currency-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
"x-rapidapi-key": "a240c5c786msh2c570127dc5c757p195ec7jsn551b0fc491a5"
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

la fuente es:
https://rapidapi.com/fixer/api/fixer-currency?endpoint=5c11955de4b0a62b0424dd36

lo envie con mi codigo completo para ver si se puede realizar por ejemplo necesito saber que un (1 USD = 99,00 HTG)

la pregunta es como veo la variable quiero algo como esto:

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

segun veo esto es posible por que en el cuadro abajo sale eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. En la respuesta que muestras no hay ninguna clave llamada `HTG`. Tampoco se entiende por qué tienes la etiqueta PHP cuando la llamada a la API la puedes hacer y manejar desde el cliente.

Comment: Es que no entiendo y lo quiero hacer en PHP hice una calculadora de USD a BTC en PHP

Comment: Ya, pero, ¿por qué lo haces en PHP? ¿Te exigen que sea en PHP? El código que muestras es Javascript y dado que la información parece estar en una API no necesitas PHP a no ser que vayas a usar recursos del servidor o cosas así. Tampoco se entiende, viendo la respuesta de la URL que pones, cómo debe ser la conversión ¿? En dicha respuesta hay un valor y su equivalente en dólares, pero no se llama `HTG`. La pregunta es confusa.

Comment: No deberías poner como públicas tanto el host real como la key, espero la edición no te moleste

Comment: de hecho no me importa ponerla publica me da =

Comment: la puse para que me ayuden por que no entiendo y necesito hacer una calculadora con BTC a HTC y USD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo con PHP solo necesitas usar [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php) y asi poder obtener los datos de esa API

```php
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $params = http_build_query([
    "fsyms" => "BTC,HTC",
    "tsyms" => "USD"
  ]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?".$params);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $out = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
<ul>
  <li>1 HTC = <?php echo rtrim(sprintf('%.10f', $out->HTC->USD), '0'); ?> USD</li>
  <li>1 BTC = <?php echo rtrim(sprintf('%.10f', $out->BTC->USD), '0'); ?> USD</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Un detalle MUYYYYY importante amigo el precio de 1 USD a HTG (moneda haitiana) no sale o si? por que la busque y hay no esta encambio la de arriba tiene los valores de muchas monedas y la princpal para mi es la HTG

Comment: voy a tener que aprender json para sacar las variables en php lol las necesito en php bro u.u

Comment: bro me salio este error O.o no pego una xD Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\htg\index.php on line 3

Comment: hermanito entendistes muy bien mi respuesta, perooooo esa API es de paga y me acabn de dar una FREE tu decides si te califico esta como positiva y me ayudas mejor con este link si no es molestia que ODIOOOOO que esto me pase me dice que message You are not subscribed to this API. y sin embargo me diero este link que creo es mejor no se que digas bro. http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/btc.json

Comment: yo nada mas necesito cojer el de btc, usd y htc con una sola basta solo le cambio las variables no sirve? solo necesito los valores de las monedas nada mas eso

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez mira mi respuesta otra vez ;)

Comment: Exelente jajajaja xDDD muchas gracias hermanito

Comment: esta buenisimo pero es HTG (Moneda haitiana) NO HTC

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez hay muy poca información sobre esa criptomoneda

Comment: la verdad que si

Comment: pero bueno ya solucione

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://fixer-fixer-currency-v1.p.rapidapi.com/convert");

req.query({
    "from": "USD",
    "to": "HTG",
    "amount": "1"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "fixer-fixer-currency-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "a240c5c786msh2c570127dc5c757p195ec7jsn551b0fc491a5"
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

Te devuelve un JSON similar y ya puedes obtener el valor desde ahí

```
{
"success":true
"query":{
"from":"USD"
"to":"ILS"
"amount":12
}
"info":{
"timestamp":1544654047
"rate":3.74915
}
"date":"2018-12-12"
"result":44.9898
}
```

Comment: No entendi la respuesta no se que lenguaje se usa hay y dos creo que me estas dando el valor no real si no que le fijas el valor al HTC no se si estoy equiocado pero en la linea 2 te falta como que un TRUE y creo que falta mas codigo

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez su código y su respuesta esta bien e incluso es mejor que la mía xD